# How to “push” to Home view controller after successful login

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using storyboard in ios9. i have two screens. one is login screen and another one is homeviewcontroller. If login success i have to navigate homeviewcontroller. This is my requirement. jam using json parser and protocol is NSURLSession for login page. if login is success then navigate to homeviewcontroller. so i am writing some code. Login is success. After a successful login they did not navigate to homeviewcontroller. I am new to storyboard. Anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

NSString *user_name=userName.text;

NSString *pass_word=password.text;

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/Service/security.svc/LoginUser?strUserName=%@&strPassword=%@",pass_word,user_name]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                                 NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                 NSError *error)

{

if (!error)

{

NSError *JSONError = nil;


NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                     options:0 error:&JSONError];


if (JSONError)

{

NSLog(@"Serialization error: %@", JSONError.localizedDescription);

}

else

{

NSLog(@"Response: %@", dictionary);


NSString *str=[dictionary objectForKey:@"Status"];

tokenVlue=[dictionary objectForKey:@"message"];

NSLog(@"Token Value is :%@",tokenVlue);

NSLog(@"login Status :%@",str);

if([str isEqualToString:@"Success"])

{

HomeViewController *secondViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}

}

}

else

{

NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}

}];

// Start the task.

[task resume];

}
```

Comment: LoginViewController should have UINavigationController for Push

Comment: Just make your new view controller a root after deleting subViews :

Answer (score 1):

Use Segues for the same. Control-Drag from the `LoginViewController` to the `HomeViewController` to create a segue. Give an identifier for the segue, for example: `"LoginToHomeSegue"`. Make sure the segue is of kind `Show`. It is equal to pushing a view controller. `Show Detail` is equal to present view controller. Then after successful login, in `LoginViewController` class, just call the following function:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginToHomeSegue", sender: self)
```

That will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard there is an option to mark `Initial View Controller`, drag drop an UINaviagtionController (as initial view controller) and LoginViewController should be its root view controller. Draw a push segue from LoginViewController to HomeViewController and write this code on the event when user logged in:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeSegue" sender:self];
```

where `HomeSegue` is the segue identifier from LoginViewController to `HomeViewController`

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:**storyboardName** bundle:nil];
HomeViewController *secondViewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Verify your storyboard id for HomeViewController is homeViewController
and give the correct storyboard name

OR

You can use segue also refer the tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Comment: still i doesnot navigate to homeviewcontroller.. i am writing like this  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                                  HomeViewController *secondViewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];
                                                  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

Comment: okei put some break points and check values of the following  :->     storyboard, secondViewController,self.navigationController

Comment: embed the loginviewcontroller  in navigation controller